# What is the specific behavior of Gradle caching?

Tags: caching, gradle

Obviously, it will download if we don't have that specific artifact in the cache, but under what specific circumstances, if any, does Gradle expire dependencies? For example, if the artifact changes, will Gradle re-download the artifact? If the artifact is X days old but has not changed, will it re-download? If the artifact hasn't been accessed or used in X days, will it be removed from the cache? What if that drive partition is filling up?  Are there any configuration options that affect these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[23.2.4. Use Dynamic Versions and Changing Modules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules)

Pay close attention to that last paragraph in the section of the manual noted above.

Comment: IMHO, this model is overly simplistic. If there's a non-snapshot release, it shouldn't be installed in the user's cache. It should be stored in a cache that is central to that entire machine in order to reduce redundancy.  If 5 builds on different projects use the same box, but different users or are building in different threads, some Dependant on each other and some not (Think Jenkins CI), these should go in a system wide cache to reduce redundancy. Why is this always an after thought? Anyway, aren't we probably going to wind up with something like this anyway after Java 9?